# Parse iOS Destroy Button (Password Validation Dependent) Client side

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm starting to create a lot more features for users in my app. I've run into some app structure issues.

lets say I have User Fooman

Fooman wants to edit his account, delete some objects(wall posts), update his friends list etc.

Fooman is logged in to do all of these. But footman isn't the one using the device at the moment. It's fooman son (foobaby). Foobaby decides to just be a son and delete things erroneously. I have an option for users to delete their account client side. I present them an alert view to confirm that's the choice they meant to select. After they confirm that, another view populates with a 'Destroy' (or delete button) that will delete the User, plus all relations/pointers/data connected to it. Before that button is enabled a password validation check is required so it's not done by a foobaby. However, with Parse, this has proved to be problematic client side. I don't use cloud functions because, well, simply put, at this point in time my app is one platform and doesn't really need to use it.

Is there any workaround anyone has come up with that's quick/efficient, *API friendly* for validating a textField.text with the `[PFUser currentUser].password` whilst maintaining security of course.

I code in Objective-C :)

Note: I have tried numerous things but nothing seems to work outside of trying to log them in against the user input (`UITextField`), which doesn't feel like the right way to do it in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an unusual requirement.  The idea of a logged-in user is that the app trusts the user.  A persisted logged-in user on the device means that the app trusts whomever is holding the device.  So FooBaby is trusted, because FooDad let him hold the phone.

Some apps put up a barrier to establish thoughtfulness, like the Parse data browser requiring that you type the name of a class before you drop it.  But this establishes thoughtfulness, not trust.  (For a child, I guess it also establishes minimal competence, in case FooBaby knows how to press buttons, but not how to spell).

Otherwise, I can't think of how to do it besides requiring a login, which you mentioned you find unappealing (though you didn't say why).  Excluding that, I don't think there's a way to do it without spoiling security with something like keeping an in-the-clear copy of the password.

Comment: I don't feel it's unusual for a password validation to a destroy button at all. The only time I will use this method is when the user wants to deactivate/delete their account entirely. Not so out of the norm w/social media platforms. (Facebook, Twitter, etc all do it) I suppose my example was too generic. I don't plan on asking them to reverify themselves every alteration, just when it matters like deleting an account. My example was the chance that that destroy button was pressed on accident (however it's done) would ask for validation. But I was just getting a second opinion. Thank you.

Comment: And sorry again, I just didn't feel like trying to log them in again was user friendly. I'm not a fan of doing things I'm not educated on. It just didnt feel right to do it that way is all i was saying. Especially since I'm not exactly sure what happens to the previously PFUser session, even if it's the same one, and the app-wide cache it persists. So I guess I was on the right path, i just wasnt sure what it would mean for the sessions but a second, similar, opinion reassures me the process is ok. I just assumed there would be something more 'dumbed' down i.e. `textField.text isEqualToString`

Comment: No worries.  I think I understand you.  I would just remember to distinguish wether you want to establish trust, or establish forethought on the part of the user.  The latter is much easier.